# Converting Time to A Numeric instead of Character

Tags: r, time

I have a data frame which has a column labeled Time to indicate when an order was placed, all of the Time values are in a 07:16:00 format. I would like to convert these from a character to a numeric so that I can add another column that says the type of menu it was based off of the time.

Using as.numeric all the values become NA. Also tried to use strptime and values were also NA.

Answer (score 1):

An approach is using `lubridate`s `hms`.

> Transforms a character or numeric vector into a period object with
> the specified number of hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
library(lubridate)

times <- c("07:16:00", "07:18:12", "08:56:00")

new_time <- hms(times)

new_time - new_time[1]
[1] "0S"        "2M 12S"    "1H 40M 0S"
```